# "Please do not repeat the mistake" and "Please do not repeat the mistake again"

Tags: word-choice

> Please do not repeat the mistake.
>
> Please do not repeat the mistake again.

Should the again be omitted? “Repeat” means “do again”. So to “repeat again” means “to do again again”. Is the second sentence grammatically wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are grammatical; they mean different things.  You use the first sentence the first time someone makes a mistake, and the second sentence when they make the exact same mistake *again*.

Comment: Perhaps more to the point, even if this were redundant, which it is not, the answer would still be the same. Redundancy, repetition, pleonasms, tautologies, or what have you, are not grammatically wrong. That's why they exist in the first place. (Which is to say, of course they could still exist otherwise, but only as one-off errors not worth being noticed, much less discussed.) OP's very own question is full of redundancies. It can be easily cut by half.

Comment: Hmm, could it be there due to the emphasis too? Like emphasizing on not to repeat the mistake AGAIN.